# I get exception message using log4j

Tags: java, exception, log4j

I am using log4j to log errors to a file, however, I keep getting the following error when ever I run my program, although the log file gets created and the error is logged in the file, but only when I quit the program

Error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:372)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:403)
    at javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4.init(JavaFXApplication4.java:227)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:788)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [log4j.properties].
```

Code:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
...
catch(SQLException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error on Database connection");
                    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                    logger.error("Your log message", e);
                }
```

Configuration file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=/log/example.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

[image]

Comment: please, show Project hierarchy. thanks

Comment: Check out the hierarchy in my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont even need to set the log4j.properteis file. Log4j finds it by itself if its in root folder.

Comment: should I remove PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");, but then it doesn't log

Comment: Try to use use logger instaed of using PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

Comment: I am using osx and also linus, but currently testing on osx

Comment: I am a bit confused about your structure but i think you should move your property file to the parent folder.

Comment: I uncommented //        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); and now is working. but why is the file written to after i quit the program

Comment: What do you mean by written to ?

Comment: the logging is only added to the log file when the app is closed

Comment: most probably it is because the program is open a stream a close it after you close the program. This is something different from Windows that creates local copies for open file.

Comment: In one word.. changes are written when you closed of flush the stream.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `log4j.properties` file is not found in class path, either include its folder in classpath or provide absolute path.